# Use javascript regex to validate mobile number

Tags: javascript, regex

The following is my code:

```
<html>
<title>Validate Phone Number</title>
<head>
<script>
function testnumber() {
    var ph = new RegExp("^[789]\d{9}$");
    num = {10 digit phone number}
    alert(ph.test(num));
}
testnumber();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to validate mobile phone number which starts with 7/8/9 and is 10 digit.
But it alerts false for any phone number given as input.

Please tell me where am I going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll find a regex tester very useful like [this one for exemple](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: [This](https://regexr.com/) would help as well

Comment: @3Dos The tester gives me string matched. But getting false alerted in code for same input

Comment: To define a ``\`` in a string literal, you must use two backslashes. A too common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, your formatting was slightly off:

```
function testnumber() {
    var ph = new RegExp(/^[789]\d{9}$/);
    num = 7123435498; // example number
    alert(ph.test(num));
}
testnumber();
```

Comment: This worked. (y) Thanks

Comment: @YashParekh please mark as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `HTML` only option too

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
 Phone number: <input type="text" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" title="Enter valid number">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's cool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your existing regex doesn't work for following reason

**`\d` in a string literal is evaluated to `d`**

*Hence, you can take following two approaches*

**1)** Try this

```
var ph = new RegExp("^[789]{1}[0-9]{9}$");
var num = "7894543542";
console.log( ph.test(num) ); //true
```

- `^` matches start of the string
- `[789]` matches one of 7,8 or 9
- `[0-9]{9}` matches 9 digits
- `$` matches end of the string

**2)** Your regex works fine as well if you passed a regex literal instead of a string.

```
var ph = new RegExp(/^[789]\d{9}$/);
var num = "7894543542";
ph.test(num); //true
```